# Adding host name in wrapper.conf

Tags: java, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

I'm using Java Service Wrapper ([here](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)) v. 3.2.3 on Linux RHEL 5.4.

I need to add hostname to system properties (see [here](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-envvars.html#definition)):

```
wrapper.java.additional.13=-DHOSTNAME="%WRAPPER_HOSTNAME%"
```

The problem is that WRAPPER_HOST_NAME Since ver.3.3.2, WRAPPER_HOSTNAME Since ver.3.3.6.

Is there're a way to use external command to get hostname?

Is there any other unique system property I can use across several identical machine?

Comment: afaik HOSTNAME is not unique identifier, isn't it?

Comment: I guess WRAPPER_HOSTNAME refers to same hostname string returned by hostname command (Linux)

Comment: but it still isn't unique identifier, it's just hostname which can be changed

Comment: @Marek - yep, this still satisfies my requirements

Answer (score 0):

If running on Windows, try

```
wrapper.java.additional.13=-DHOSTNAME="%COMPUTERNAME%"
```

Comment: Not expanded, so I guess is not supported by v.3.2.3. Do you have are reference to it in Java Service Wrapper documentation?

Comment: @dimba, oups ... it is Windows specific, sorry about that :-(